# Debugging self hosted service servicestack

Tags: servicestack, fiddler

I am checking servicestack [example projects](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples)
Is that possible to debug self hosted service?

```
namespace StarterTemplates.Common
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Define your ServiceStack web service request (i.e. the Request DTO).
    /// </summary>  
    [Description("ServiceStack's Hello World web service.")]
    [Route("/hello")]
    [Route("/hello/{Name*}")]
    public class Hello
    {       
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Define your ServiceStack web service response (i.e. Response DTO).
    /// </summary>
    public class HelloResponse : IHasResponseStatus
    {       
        public string Result { get; set; }      
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create your ServiceStack web service implementation.
    /// </summary>
    public class HelloService : ServiceBase<Hello>
    {
        protected override object Run(Hello request)
        {
            return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
        }
    }
}
```

Runs under port 32.
From fiddler `http://localhost:32/servicestack/xml/syncreply/Hello?Name=World` but I get always 404 error.
Any ideas ?

Other non  self hosted examples run as charm.

Any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-hosted services aren't hosted under a `/custompath`, try instead:

```
http://localhost:32/xml/syncreply/Hello?Name=World
```

The example projects looks dated as the recommended way to create a service is to use [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api), e.g:

```
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
}
```

There are also [new routing options](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) which lets you access the same service with the shorter:

```
http://localhost:32/xml/reply/Hello?Name=World
```

And if you've got custom routes defined you can use different ways to ask for Content Negotiation, e.g:

```
http://localhost:32/hello?Name=World&format=xml
http://localhost:32/hello.xml?Name=World
```

Comment: If anybody's coming here from Jon Sonmez's plural sight course it's `http://localhost:3542/json/reply/Entry`